# Using sourceMaps with CSS Modules

Tags: reactjs, webpack, source-maps, css-modules

I am using babel-plugin-react-css-modules and I would like to use source maps with css modules.

My **webpack.config.js** looks like this

```
{
        test: /\.local\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader?sourceMap',
          'css-loader?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
          'postcss-loader?sourceMap',
          'sass-loader?sourceMap',
          {
            loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
            options: {
              resources: [
                /* uncomment for import of Bootstrap variables and mixins */
                // path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss'),
                // path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_mixins.scss'),
                path.resolve(__dirname, './src/client/assets/styles/variables.scss'),
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```

So I am adding sourceMaps inside my webpack config any they are working. I am also setting `devtool: 'source-map'` When I inspect inside my console i get this, so it is working partly. I can see from what file is the style. But the problem is the name, I want original class name to be displayed, not this long generated string?

[image]

Comment: i really dn get it.. wat do mean by original class name.. ? u mean u want ur sass to be displayed in the styles section of the debugger?? 

Comment: I want that instead of getting this displayed ```.scenes-routeComponents-home-components-___titleComponent-local__container___REuKC .scenes-routeComponents-home-components-___titleComponent-local__imageRotate___R58vw```
as my className I just get this ```imageRotate```without all the generated css module name.

Comment: chrome debugger is not intelligent enough.. you have to look into solutions in the library that u r using to generate the classname..

Comment: Yeah, That's why I am hopping for help. I din't find any soultion yet. It's also not showing me the correct line number of the style.

Answer (score 0):

This long name is configured by localIdentName in css-loader. In order to have only original class name you can update css-loader to:

```
  'css-loader?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[local]',
```

Common description of  localIdentName is at [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader)

If you are looking for other predefined tokens, check the [documentation for loader-utils](https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils#interpolatename) (which is used by css-loader)

Comment: Can you provide some reference/Documents

Comment: Sure, I've added useful links about what is this localIdentName and what tokens could be used there

Comment: Thanks Ksenia. I know that that but that is then defeating the purpose that I am using CSS modules for. I want to generate that long name so that class names dont clash and I can have a class name called for example "button" inside every component. If I only use [local] they will clash. I just wnat to map them to original file name while developing to show in console when I inspect it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible to achieve in Google Chrome directly using source maps, but you can use different `localIdentName` in development and in production.

Here's the idiomatic example:

```
localIdentName: (isProduction
  ? '[contenthash]' // using obfuscated hashnames in production
  : '[path][name]__[local]' // using more readable class names during development
),
```